# IOS creating a new distribution certificate without revoking old one

Tags: ios, xcode

Tried reading around but there's a lot of information around which negates itself

I have an app which I built with a certain distribution certificate, those certificate's private keys are lost to me now...

I want to create a new distribution certificate, and a new provisioning profile without revoking the old one... because the old needs to remain active on the places I've installed it on... I can't afford to re-publish it.

will uploading a new certificate ruin the old certificate?

I should mention I am using an enterprise account to distribute the app.

do I have ANY other choice other than revoking and re-install my app on all devices for my account?

Comment: Do you have access to the Apple developer program account that created the original certificate?

Comment: if you mean the enterprise account then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading the new certificate to the Apple dev a/c and creating the new profile will not ruin the old certificate. As long as the old certificate is valid, application with that certificate will continue to work.

Comment: [Apple's iOS Developer's portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action)